# Prove that there exists a graph with these points such that G is connected

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, proof-verification, combinations

> Let us have $n \geq 3$ points in a square whose side length is $1$. Prove that there exists a graph with these points such that $G$ is connected, and 
>   $$\sum_{\{v_i,v_j\} \in E(G)}{|v_i - v_j|} \leq 10\sqrt{n}$$
>   Prove also the $10$ in the inequality can't be replaced with $1$.

I think I should use Erdös-Renyi random graph model to prove the existence of a connected graph. In that model, if an edge appears with probability $p$, then, for example, a particular connected graph with $n-1$ edges appear with $p^{n-1}(1-p)^{\binom{n}{2} - (n - 1)}$. Is this enough to show a connected graph exists since this probability should be greater than zero? Regardless of this, I found proofs showing that the expected distance between two points picked on a unit square is around $0.52$, but I think that is not useful.  Should I look for the expected value of the total length of $n$ points maybe?

---

I was trying to prove the upper bound $2\sqrt{n} + 2$ on TSP Path length in the following link before an answer came. I'll leave it here in case it works for somebody.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#TSP_path_length_for_random_sets_of_points_in_a_square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random graph won't help you. After all, it is clear that *some* connected graph exists (e.g., the complete graph), but we might need to derive bounds for the minimal spanning tree.

For some $c\ge 1$ (in the problem statement, $c=10$), we may want to prove that the total edge length of a minimal spanning tree of any set of $n$ points in the unit square is $\le c\sqrt n$. We do this by induction on $n$, noting that $n=0$ and $n=1$ the total length is trivially $=0$, and for $n=2$, the worst case length is $\sqrt 2$. 
For $n=3$, the shortest tree we can find for three points in three vertices of the square is $2$, so we certainly need $c\ge\frac 2{\sqrt 3}>1$. This already answers the second part of the question.

Let $c=2\sqrt 2$. Then

**Claim.** $n$ points in the unit square are the vertices of a connected graph of total edge length $\ell\le c\sqrt n$.

*Proof.* The claim is trivially true for $n=0$ and for $n=1$.
Suppose we are given $n\ge 2$ points in the unit square and know that the bound holds for all smaller sets of points.
Let $k=\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor$ and tile the square into $k\times k$ smaller squares.

If $n=k^2$, it *may* happen that each tile contains exactly one of the points. We can then join the point by $k^2-1$ times joining points in adjacent tiles (e.g., in a snake-like pattern across the tiles). The edges used herein are all $\le \frac{\sqrt 5}k$ ($=$the diagonal through a rectangle formed from two adjacent tiles), thus giving a total length of 
$$ \ell\le(k^2-1)\frac{\sqrt 5}k<k\sqrt 5=\sqrt 5\sqrt n<c\sqrt n.$$

In all other arrangements of $n^2$ points, as well as when $n>k^2$ (pigeon-hole!), we find at least one tile with at least two of the points in it. Ignore one of these points, then use the induction hypothesis to join the other $n-1$ points with edges of total length $\le c\sqrt {n-1}$, and join the ignored point to a "tile-mate" with an additional edge of length $\le \frac {\sqrt 2}k$ ($=$the diagonal of a tile) for a total length of
$$\begin{align}\ell&\le c\sqrt {n-1}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{ k}\\
&=c\sqrt n-\frac c{\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt n}+\frac{\sqrt 2}k\\
&<c\sqrt n-\frac{c}{2\sqrt n}+\frac{\sqrt 2}k\\
&\le c\sqrt n-\frac{c}{2\sqrt n}+\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt n}\\
&=c\sqrt n.\end{align}$$
Hence the claim follow. $\square$

---

We have already seen above that the claim becomes false for $n=3$ if we let $c=1$.
  But there are also arbitrarily large counterexamples: Consider $n=2k^2$, and the $n$ points $(\frac i{2k-1},\frac j{2k-1})$ with $0\le i\le 2k-1$, $0\le j\le 2k-1$, $2\equiv j\pmod 2$. Then any two of these are at least $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2k-1}$ apart, and we need $n-1$ edges, thus the length of any connecting graph is 
$$\ell \ge (2k^2-1)\frac{\sqrt 2}{2k-1}=k\sqrt 2+\underbrace{\frac{1-\frac 1k}{2-\frac 1k}\sqrt 2}_{\to \frac1{\sqrt 2}}>\sqrt n.$$

---

We can try to be more systematic: Cover each of the $n$ points with a disk of radius $r$. Then all these disks are within the square obtained by extending the unit square by $r$ in each direction. If the disks are disjoint, they cannot beat the densest packing, i.e., 
$$ n\pi r^2\le \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3}\cdot (1+2r)^2,$$
or:
$$ (2\sqrt 3 n-4) r^2-4r-1\le 0.$$
If we let $r=\frac a{\sqrt n}$ for some fixed $a>\frac 1{\sqrt{2\sqrt 3}}$, this condition amounts to 
$$2\sqrt 3a^2-1-\frac {4a^2}n+\frac{4a}{\sqrt n}\le0 $$
and is false for all sufficiently large $n$. We conclude that for all $n\gg 0$, we find two points if distance $\le \frac{2a}{\sqrt n}$.
Thus if we pick $\ell_0$ such that $\ell\le \ell_0+c\sqrt n$ holds for all small $n$, we can use induction like above for larger $n$ and show 
$$ \ell \le \ell_0+c\sqrt{n-1}+\frac{2a}{\sqrt n}\le \ell_0+c\sqrt n$$
provided
$$ \frac{2a}{\sqrt n}\le c(\sqrt n-\sqrt{n-1})=\frac{c}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n-1}}$$
for which 
$ c\ge 4a$, so ultimately
$$ c>\frac 4{\sqrt{2\sqrt 3}}\approx 2.1491398636470838391066763134118611543.$$
is sufficient.
This improves the above result to

**Claim 2.** There exists $\ell_0$ such that for all $n$, any $n$ points in the unit square are the vertices of a connected graph of total edge length $\ell\le \ell_0+2.14914\sqrt n$. $\square$

Since the constant $\frac 4{\sqrt{2\sqrt 3}}$ stems right from the densest disk packing, I *guess* that it it is indeed the infimum of all factors before $\sqrt n$ that can be used in claim 2. I.e.,

**Conjecture.** Let $c<\frac 4{\sqrt{2\sqrt 3}}$ and $\ell_0>0$. Then there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ and $n$ points in the unit square such that the minimum spanning tree of these points hast total edge length $>\ell_0+c\sqrt n$.