# A conjecture about minimal spanning trees among points in the unit square

Tags: trees, packing-problem

For $n\in\Bbb N$, consider $n$ points $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ in the unit square $Q=[0,1]^2$. Let $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ denote the minimal total edge length of a tree with $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ as vertices.
Let 
$$ L_n=\sup_{x_1,\ldots, x_n\in Q}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$
Then in [Prove that there exists a graph with these points such that G is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004319/prove-that-there-exists-a-graph-with-these-points-such-that-g-is-connected/3005261#3005261), it was asked to show that $$\tag1\forall n\ge 3\colon L_n\le c\sqrt n $$
is true for $c=10$ and false for $c=1$.

In my answer (see there), an inductive argument based on subdividing the square showed that $(1)$ is true for $c=2\sqrt 2\approx 2.828$, and has infinitely many counterexamples for $c=1$.

In a later addendum to my answer, I showed that 
$$ \tag2\exists \ell_0\colon \forall n\colon L_n<\ell_0+c\sqrt n$$
holds for any $c>\frac 4{\sqrt{2\sqrt 3}}\approx 2.149$ and dared to

**Conjecture.** $$\inf\{\,c\in\Bbb R\mid (2) \text{ is true}\,\}=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2\sqrt 3}}. $$

I dared to do so because the constant stems from the factor $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3}$ known from the [densest circle packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing).

My question for you us: Is my conjecture true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Silly me! After a good night's rest, this direction is of course the trivial part!*

For $m\gg 0$, the lattice $\frac 1m\Bbb Z[\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}2]$ has $\frac {2m}{\sqrt 3}+O(1)$ rows of $m+O(1)$ points each in the unit square, so that's $n=\frac 2{\sqrt 3}m² +O(m)$ points with minimal distance $\frac 1m$ between them. Any tree with these vertices certainly has edge length
$$\ell =\frac{n-1}m=\frac 2{\sqrt 3}m+O(1) =\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt[4]3}\sqrt n+O(1)=\frac 2{\sqrt{2\sqrt 3}}\sqrt n+O(1).$$
I suppose, a spurious factor of $2$ somehow slipped into the calculations leading to the conjecture.